# Apparel Recognition Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-recognition

I am looking for an algorithm that given a photo / image, it can recognize and cut out the main piece of apparel on it. There will be only a piece of apparel on the photo, meaning it is not a model wearing different pieces, but just an image with that piece of apparel only and the rest will be the background.

Do any of you know such open source solution/algorithm for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try amazon mechanical turk service. It costs but might get the job done.

http://aws.amazon.com/mturk/

If all else fails in your search to find a free algorithm!

Answer (score 0):

Buy yourself a book on image recognition. You will have to develop a training set, and train your code to recognise apparel. No-one is giving away a trained, optimised, commercial-purpose image recognition system for free.